# Merging survival data with time varying covariates

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, hazard, proportional-hazards

In merging the data in R the censored observations are merged well but the observed subjects are not. For example, the second subject had an event at time 0.546. How can I merge the time varying covariate (x2) such that an event is only observed at this time only after merging.

```
   id      time status
1   1 2.0767599      0
2   2 0.5463428      1
3   3 0.2802100      0
4   4 1.2825777      0
5   5 0.2700360      1
6   6 0.2388472      1
7   7 1.8876389      0
8   8 0.5704614      0
9   9 2.1770790      0
10 10 0.7846986      0
> df.td[1:10,]
       start      stop id         x2
1  0.0000000 0.3992188  1 0.00000000
2  0.3992188 0.7232557  1 0.11976564
3  0.7232557 0.8482767  1 0.21697670
4  0.8482767 2.0770000  1 0.25448301
5  0.0000000 0.4556604  2 0.00000000
6  0.4556604 0.5460000  2 0.13669812
7  0.0000000 0.0555520  3 0.00000000
8  0.0555520 0.2413055  3 0.01666560
9  0.2413055 0.2800000  3 0.07239165
10 0.0000000 0.5095888  4 0.00000000
> merge(df.td,dat,by="id")[1:10,]
   id     start      stop         x2      time status
1   1 0.0000000 0.3992188 0.00000000 2.0767599      0
2   1 0.3992188 0.7232557 0.11976564 2.0767599      0
3   1 0.7232557 0.8482767 0.21697670 2.0767599      0
4   1 0.8482767 2.0770000 0.25448301 2.0767599      0
5   2 0.0000000 0.4556604 0.00000000 0.5463428      1
6   2 0.4556604 0.5460000 0.13669812 0.5463428      1
7   3 0.0000000 0.0555520 0.00000000 0.2802100      0
8   3 0.0555520 0.2413055 0.01666560 0.2802100      0
9   3 0.2413055 0.2800000 0.07239165 0.2802100      0
10  4 0.0000000 0.5095888 0.00000000 1.2825777      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ThomasLumley says, if you only have 1 event per individual then correcting your merged result is a fairly straightforward programming exercise.

For the more general case, the `tmerge` function from the survival package is a better way to merge survival data. The syntax is more complicated, but it can handle all the usual situations. You can read about it in section 3 of the time-dependent covariates and coefficients vignette, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf

```r
library(survival)
dat1 <- data.frame(id = factor(1:5),
                   tstop = c(10,12,14,15,17),
                   status = c(1,0,1,1,1))
dat2 <- data.frame(id = rep(factor(1:5), each=2),
                   tstart = c(0,3,0,2,0,4,0,5,0,7),
                   tstop = c(3,10,2,12,4,14,5,15,7,17),
                   x1 = c(2,7,6,4,3,10,9,1,10,2))
dat1
#>   id tstop status
#> 1  1    10      1
#> 2  2    12      0
#> 3  3    14      1
#> 4  4    15      1
#> 5  5    17      1
dat2
#>    id tstart tstop x1
#> 1   1      0     3  2
#> 2   1      3    10  7
#> 3   2      0     2  6
#> 4   2      2    12  4
#> 5   3      0     4  3
#> 6   3      4    14 10
#> 7   4      0     5  9
#> 8   4      5    15  1
#> 9   5      0     7 10
#> 10  5      7    17  2
dat_final <- tmerge(dat1, dat1, id = id, 
                    status = event(tstop, status))
dat_final <- tmerge(dat_final, dat2, id = id,
                    x1 = tdc(tstart, x1))
dat_final <- dat_final[,c(1,4,2,3,5)]
dat_final
#>    id tstart tstop status x1
#> 1   1      0     3      0  2
#> 2   1      3    10      1  7
#> 3   2      0     2      0  6
#> 4   2      2    12      0  4
#> 5   3      0     4      0  3
#> 6   3      4    14      1 10
#> 7   4      0     5      0  9
#> 8   4      5    15      1  1
#> 9   5      0     7      0 10
#> 10  5      7    17      1  2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can't, basically. That isn't merging; merging doesn't alter the data that way.

It's fairly easy to fix it up afterwards in settings where there is just one event per person

```
merged_data$status[ merged_data$time<merged_data$stop] <-0
```

Or, if you're worried about floating-point equality comparisons[1], sort in reverse time order so that the actual event (if any) is the first record

```
merged_data <- merged_data[order(merged_data$time, decreasing=TRUE),]
merged_data$status[duplicated(merged_data$id)]<-0
```

[1] you typically don't need to be: we're testing for equality on what are typically copies of the same data value, not separately computed values